# Format chart.js x-axis labels to specific timezone

Tags: typescript, chart.js, momentjs, luxon

I am building a chart.js line chart that displays time on the x axis. I intentionally pass the data to the chart in utc format, like so:

```
[{
 y: 143,
 x: "2020-06-17T19:50:50Z"
},
...
]
```

It seems as if the chart automatically formats the tick labels to the timezone of the user viewing the chart. But sometimes the data is viewed in a different timezone than which it is collected, so I want the tick labels to appear in that zone, which I have stored in `localStorage.timezone`, which will be an exact string like "America/New_York".

How can I display the x axis labels in my desired timezone?

Here's my x-axis configuration:

```
       xAxes: [{
            min: leftEnd,
            max: rightEnd,
            maxBarThickness: 10,
            type: 'time',
            time: {
              displayFormats: {
                'second': 'MMM DD h:mm a',
                'minute': 'MMM DD h:mm a',
                'hour': 'MMM DD h:mm a',
                'day': 'MMM DD h:mm a',
                'month': 'MMM DD h:mm a',
                'year': 'MMM DD h:mm a',
              },
              parser: function (utcMoment) {
                console.log( DateTime.fromISO(utcMoment, { zone: localStorage.timezone })
                .toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_FULL_WITH_SECONDS)) //logs as desired
                return DateTime.fromISO(utcMoment, { zone: localStorage.timezone })
                .toLocaleString(DateTime.DATETIME_FULL_WITH_SECONDS) 
                // but has no effect on the actual chart label
              }           
            },
            ticks: {
              maxTicksLimit: 11,
              autoSkip: true,
              maxRotation: 0,
              minRotation: 0
            },
            gridLines: {
              drawTicks: true,
              tickMarkLength: 10,
              display: false
            }
          }],
```

I use the luxon/moment library to format the date that comes in, and it console logs correctly (i.e. `June 17, 2020, 9:11:20 AM EDT`) but that format is NOT appearing at all on the actual render of the chart. It still looks like `June 17 6:11 AM` (since that was specified in the displayFormat object, but removing this doesn't help)

I have also tried specifying `timezone: localStorage.timezone` but no luck

If it helps, this is all constructed in an Angular component.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With Chart.js 3.x and [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/) you can pass the timezone as an option to chartjs-adapter-luxon, e.g:

```
options: {
    scales: {
        x: {
            type: 'time',
            time: {
                unit: 'second',
                displayFormats: {
                    second: 'MMM d, yyyy, h:mm:ss a'
                }
            },
            adapters: {
                date: {
                    zone: 'UTC+6'
                }
            },
            ticks: {
                source: 'data'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

source:

https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-luxon/blob/v1.1.0/README.md#configuration

https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-adapter-luxon/blob/v1.1.0/test/specs/luxon-adapter.spec.js#L25-L29

Answer (score 0):

Most other suggestions on this topic point towards using a parser like your example. For whatever reason I was not able to get this to work for me. Like you described, I never saw any visual change to my chart based on what I put in my parser.

I WAS able to get the following to work using Chart.js 2.7.0. Note that this same solution does not work using later versions of Chart.js (I tried versions 2.7.2 and 2.9.4 to no avail).

This will display the x axis labels in the specified format.

```
xAxes: [{
    type: 'time',
    time: {
      timezone: 'America/Boise'}}]
```